# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 and could not convert string to float

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to create if else odd and even code in python. I am getting 2 errors pls refer below.

```
n = int(raw_input())
    if n%2 == 1:
```

The above code is raising error

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'if n % 2 == 1:'

I modified the code to use float

```
n = float(raw_input())
    if n % 2 = 1 :

ValueError: could not convert string to float: if n % 2 = 1 :
```

Please help on this issue

Comment: Are you using REPL? Your `if` statement doesn't get evaluated by the REPL, but rather taken by `raw_input().`

Comment: Indent your code properly

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if n%2==0:
    code(when number is even)
else:
    code(when number is odd)
```